# How do I fix Uncaught ReferenceError in Typescript when trying to import class from external file?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, import, export

I have a class in a an external file called DataTablesSettings.ts which simply just returns an object.

now i am trying to use this class in another file, but when i try to import this class, I see an error in the console stating `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.`

**DataTablesSettings.ts**

```
export class DataTableSetting implements IGetDataTableSetting {

    private _setting: Object;

    constructor(bFilter: boolean, pageLength: Number, paging: boolean, autoWidth: boolean, fixedColumns: boolean, scrollX: boolean, columns: Object[]) {
        this._setting = {
            bFilter: bFilter,
            pageLength: pageLength,
            paging: paging,
            autoWidth: autoWidth,
            fixedColumns: fixedColumns,
            scrollX: scrollX,
            columns: columns
        }
    }

    getSettings: () => Object
    = function () { return this._setting; }
}

interface IGetDataTableSetting {
    getSettings: () => Object;
}
```

This is how i import the external class

`import {DataTableSetting} from "./DataTableSetting";`

And i use it like

```
this const inventoryDataTableSetting = new DataTableSetting(false, 10, true, true, true, true, inventoryTableColumns);
```

Comment: `this const inventoryDataTableSetting = ...` looks suspect, surely `this` shouldn't be there? (That said, I don't think that's why you're getting the `require` error, but it may well be the *next* problem...)

Comment: What module bundler are you using?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder initially i did not have the require.js file in my project, now i added it and im getting a different error  which is `: Module name "DataTableSetting" has not been loaded yet for context`

Comment: Just adding `require` won't solve the problem. Bundling is both a build step and inclusion of a library.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is your solution ?

Comment: Pick a bundler (Webpack, Browserify, etc.), follow the steps for using it.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that browsers don't support a `require` call natively.

In a comment you wrote:

> initially i did not have the require.js file in my project, now i added it and im getting a different error which is : `Module name "DataTableSetting" has not been loaded yet for context`

That's because your TypeScript compiler is producing CommonJS modules but RequireJS loads only AMD modules. It has support to *facilitate* using CommonJS modules in that you just need to wrap the CommonJS modules in `define(function (require)` to get them to be understandable by RequireJS. But it does not load *unaltered* CommonJS modules.

Options:

1. You could change your `tsconfig.json` to have `"module": "amd"`, recompile, and then RequireJS could load your modules.
2. You could pick a bundler like Browserify or Webpack to bundle your modules into a single bundle. You'd let the TypeScript compiler produce CommonJS modules. Both Browserify and Webpack can process CommonJS modules.

I've used each of the options above at various times.

Comment: Hi, thank you soo much for a very good explanation as to why it doesnt work. I already have gulp in my project which i use to create minified js files. can this be used, I have added the require.js file in there and i have been able to minify that along with my other JS files. but now i get `exports is not defined(…)` ... do you strongly advice i use WebPack ? I am new to it.

Comment: You cannot use a "plain minifier" to do the job. An example of a "plain minifier" would be UglifyJS: it loads and minify generic JavaScript code but has no knowledge of module systems. Yes, I do recommend Webpack. That's what I've been using with TypeScript. You can super easily integrate it into a gulp build. You don't even need a special plugin: just import the `webpack` package and call `webpack(config, callback)` in a gulp task. You should try it and if you run into a problem that the documentation or other SO questions cannot solve, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue to my original question was sold, all I had to do was create modules or namespace for each class, ensure that I reference my `DataTablesSettings.ts` file at the top of my page and then create new objects like this `new DataTableConfig.DataTableSetting`

I did not have to create bundles.